# Create select control with php and wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, select

I would like to create a field of selection with a suite of sales save in my database. but I do not know how to put make.

In MySQL my `meta_value` is: `100,200,300,400`

I want to do this:

```
 <select> 
 <option> 100 </ option>
 <option> 200 </ option>
 <option> 300 </ option>
 <option> 400 </ option>
 </select>
```

I have tried the following:

```
 <?php

 function woocommerce_quantity_input() {
 global $post,$product;
 $truc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_text', true);
 $defaults = array( $truc );

 $options .= '<option value="' . $truc . '">' . $truc . '</option>';

 echo '<select class="qty">' . $options . '</select>';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: so in this case, $truc = `"100,200,300,400"`?

Answer (score 0):

assuming `$truc = "100,200,300,400"`, you can use explode:

```
 function woocommerce_quantity_input() {
     global $post,$product;
     $truc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_text', true);

     $values = explode(',',$truc);

     echo "<select class='qty'>";
     foreach($values as $v) {
         echo "<option value='$v'>$v</option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";


 }
```

small pro-tip: if you use double quotes (`""`) instead of single quotes (`''`) for strings, you can insert variables directly instead of having to concatenate.

Comment: @user3575562 if this worked, it would be appreciated to set as answer